# weblogic abruptly stopped during deployment with fatal error

Tags: weblogic, shutdown

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000001cfe87ea753, pid=30900, tid=0x0000000000000158
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_352-b08) (build 1.8.0_352-b08)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.352-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# j  javax.validation.Validation.byDefaultProvider()Ljavax/validation/bootstrap/GenericBootstrap;+0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues
```

Getting above error, which also shutdown the weblogic.  Anyone has clue what is going on here? Please help

Comment: At first, OpenJDK is not supported with WebLogic Server. Use Oracle JDK instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it was working earlier, with OpenJDK itself, that i was able to build and deploy.   However, I made some change (quite a few) in the code caused it to behave like this!

Comment: May be something to do with the validation, "javax.validation.Validation.byDefaultProvider()Ljavax/validation/bootstrap/GenericBootstrap;+0" however, i am not able to figure out the exact issue.